# Getting `Exec format error` when trying to patch MuJoCo binaries with patchelf

Tags: linux, nixos, mujoco

I'm trying to patch the MuJoCo binaries using `patchelf`.

I've ran `patchelf --set-interpreter $(cat $NIX_CC/nix-support/dynamic-linker) ./bin/basic`. And running `patchelf --print-interpreter bin/basic` gives me `/nix/store/33idnvrkvfgd5lsx2pwgwwi955adl6sk-glibc-2.31/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`.

Now, if I run `./bin/basic` I get the output: `bash: ./bin/basic: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

Running `ldd ./bin/basic` gives me: `not a dynamic executable`, which I thought was strange.

Running `file ./bin/basic` yields:

```
./bin/basic: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /nix/store/33idnvrkvfgd5lsx2pwgwwi955adl6sk-glibc-2.31/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, not stripped
```

This looks alright to me. I thought there might be something wrong with the header so I tried `readelf -h bin/basic`, this gives me:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           AArch64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x232f70
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          293584 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         12
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         28
  Section header string table index: 26
```

So this is what I've got so far:

- `file` and `readelf -h` both think it's a dynamically linked executable
- Trying to run it fails
- `ldd` Thinks it's not a dynamically linked executable

Does anyone have an idea what could be the issue here?

I suspect that there is something invalid about the elf file which `file` and `readelf` is not picking up on.

Is there a tool I can use to search for such issues with an elf file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to use an AArch64 binary on an x86_64 system.

Comment: Thanks, totally missed that. Monkey mind see 64, monkey mind think x86_64 :)